# How to create a list within the for-loop such that all three of my hobbies are within it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop

I want to create a for-loop that prompts the user to enter their hobby three times and appends the hobby to a hobbies list. 
At the end, the hobbies list should contain all three hobbies!

This is what i tried:

```
for x in range(3):
    hobbies = input('What is your hobby?')
    print(hobbies)

list(x) #here i get: 'int' object is not iterable
```

That does not seem to work.

After reading the answers, here is what I tried now:

```
lst= []
lst = [input('What is your hobby?') for _ in range(3)]
lst.append(lst)

print(lst)
```

so the answers are in the list but there is this thing -> [...]

```
What is your hobby?as
What is your hobby?q2we
What is your hobby?sfd
['as', 'q2we', 'sfd', [...]]
```

How do i get rid of this [..]?

Comment: `lst = [input('What is your hobby?') for _ in range(3)]`

Comment: great suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note, post new questions separately. Do not edit them onto this one.

So the thing is, you are supposed to use either of those two commands. What you've basically done is defined a list by doing `lst = [input('What is your hobby?') for _ in range(3)]`

After defining the list, you've appended or added the list called `lst` to itself by doing `lst.append(lst)`
If you remove that line, your code should be good.

The line of code `lst = [input('What is your hobby?') for _ in range(3)]` is basically doing the same thing as:

```
lst = []
for x in range(3):
    hobbies = input('What is your hobby?')
    l.append(hobbies)
```

So you need not do both.

On a side note, please dont take this the wrong way but I think you should refer to a guide or course through python and get fundamental concepts clarified better. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes! thank you so much! It worked! 

I just started to code at at a university and currently doing these stuff in a python course there. I know this is very basic stuff but from time to time it gets difficult for me because I just started with it but i am fully motivated to conquer the world of python and java... and yes I am forced to learn both of them simultaneously. 

Thank you all for taking your valuable time to help me, I hope you all have a great day.

Comment: No issues, feel free to ask your doubts and be sure to upvote those who help :) Afterall, stack is a community by us and for us! I am not a professional either to be honest with you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well firstly what you're trying to do is cast he variable x outside its scope as a list. x is an integer that you're using to iterate over a set of numbers which are defined by `range(3)`
Instead what you should be doing is creating an empty list say

```
l = []
```

Then append all elements to `l` while inside the for loop.

Here's what your code should look like:

```
l = []
for x in range(3):
    hobbies = input('What is your hobby?')
    l.append(hobbies) #adding each hobby  to the list 'l'

print(hobbies) #printing out the whole list.
```

Answer (score 1):

check out the below code, it is working fine. Actually you have not appended the inputs to the original array, that's why you are not getting the desired result.

```
hobbies = []

for x in range(3):
    # storing the values in the temporary variable and appending it into the original array
    temp = input('What is your hobby?')
    hobbies.append(temp)
print(hobbies)
```